# How do you wire a 5wire mic to a 3pin connector?

Tags: microphone, xlr, wiring-diagram

I have an old table mic with a 5 wire cable that someone had hardwired into a small amp. I've repurposed the amp, and now I want to fix the mic, but I'm not having much luck finding a wiring diagram for a 3 pin XLR connector.

Anyone know how to properly connect these wires to a 3pin connector?

[image: BSI-870L]

---

I've found this:

[image]

Can I just double up the appropriate wires to make a single connection? Looks like I'd combine red with white and yellow with black?

Comment: You're not going to get an answer to this. You need to disassemble the mic and determine the internal connections for each of those wires - otherwise it will be impossible to work out which wires are for what. Also consider that the mic has a switch. Once you know the internal wiring then you will be able to work out the pinout for the XLR. Get thee to a screwdriver.

Comment: My guess is that oner or two of the wires connect to the switch that was used to control something outside the mic. That would leave one wire + ground or perhaps more for the mic. It is difficult to know though. The mic might want to be powered somehow, or it might be a dynamic mic not requiring any power. I would try by connecting any two wires to pin 2 and 3 of the XLR and then test it. If not working, change to a different kombination of wires until it works. Good luck.